# JSON Response Body of type array to Java Object

Tags: java, arrays, json, pojo, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am converting JSON response of type array into java Object class, but while doing deserialization i am getting error as

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)

**JSON Response**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Apple iPhone X",
        "price": 700,
        "rating": 4,
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Apple Mac Mini",
        "price": 900,
        "rating": 5,
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "HTC Chacha",
        "price": 200,
        "rating": 3,
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "Sony Xperia",
        "price": 600,
        "rating": 5,
        "id": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy",
        "price": 400,
        "rating": 2,
        "id": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "LG LED 5600VW",
        "price": 550,
        "rating": 1,
        "id": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "Moto Razor",
        "price": 65000,
        "rating": 4,
        "id": 9
    }
]
```

**Phones.Java (Object class model)**

```
package apiEngine.model.responses;


public class Phones {

public String name;
public Integer price;
public Integer rating;
public Integer id;

public Phones() {
}

public Phones(String name, Integer price, Integer rating, Integer id) {
super();
this.name = name;
this.price = price;
this.rating = rating;
this.id = id;
}

}
```

Converting Method where JSON response is being converted into Java object

```
private static Phones phoneResponse;
public void displaylist() {
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
        request.header("Content-Type", "application/json").header("x-access-token", token);
        response = request.get("/products");
        phoneResponse = response.getBody().as(Phones.class);
        jsonString = response.asString();
        //System.out.println("list of phone is displayed \n" + phoneResponse);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a JSON `array` as `object` - you need to get it as array, not sure if it works for `GSON`, but usually stuff like:

```
phoneResponse = response.getBody().as(Phones[].class);
```

should work.

Where `phoneResponse` has to be an array of the `Phone` class. Therefore the name `phones`"would be probably more suiting.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to convert a `JSON` array to an object. Try something like;

```
final Phones[] phoneResponses = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Phones[].class);
```

Further, I would suggest you refactor the name of your `Phones` class to `Phone` because it represents a single phone.

Comment: final Phones[] phoneResponses = response.getBody().as(Phones[].class); this worked